# Does $\mbox{Im}\left ( z \right )\geq 0$ define an affine algebraic variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k=\mathbb{C}$ and $ A=\left \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \mbox{Im}(z)\geq 0  \right \}$.
I see intuitively that this cannot be expressed as the zero locus of a finitely number of polynomials, but how can you justify that it is not a variety with the following abstract definition of an affine variety?

[image]

Comment: No, in the sense that they uses different arguments not employing the definition I cited

Comment: What would be the ring of functions in your variety?

Comment: I am not sure. It should be some function of z whose image is lying in Im(z) but I am not sure if it is defined in that way

Comment: As is, there is a structure of affine variety on $A$: just take a bijection $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and define $k[A] = \{P \circ f,\, P \in \mathbb{C}[X]\}$, with the generator being simply $f$. That doesn't rule out a proof, of course, but it does require making more explicit conditions for what it means for $A$ to be an affine algebraic variety (eg, what kind of bijections are allowed: analytically-continuous ones? Zariski-continuous ones?)

Comment: I guess Zariski-continuous ones. Anywaay intuitively it does not seem to me that (A,k[A]) defines an affine variety....

Comment: Here is a slightly pedantic remark: by your definition, a single topological space cannot define an affine variety because an affine variety is a _pair_ consisting of a space and a coordinate algebra. Do you mean to ask whether there exists a choice of $k[V]$ for this space that defines an algebraic variety as in the definition, or do you have a specific $k[V]$ in mind already?

Comment: if there exists a choice of k[V] that makes it an algebraic variety

Answer (score 0):

Per your definition, an abstract affine variety over $k$ is a pair $(V,k[V])$ consisting of a set $V$ and a $k$-algebra $k[V]$ satisfying some conditions. You have not provided a candidate $k[V]$ to use with your given $V$, and in the comments you clarified that you were interested "if there exists a choice of $k[V]$ that makes it an algebraic variety".

With $k=\Bbb C$ and the definition of an abstract affine variety as given in the post, the only restrictions on when an arbitrary set (without any other structure) can be a $V$ such that there exists a $k[V]$ so that $(V,k[V])$ is an abstract affine variety are cardinality-related. That is, we can find a $\Bbb C[V]$ which makes $(V,\Bbb C[V])$ an abstract affine variety iff $|V|$ is finite or $|V|=|\Bbb C|$. To do this, take a bijection of $V$ with either a finite set $\{1,\cdots,n\}\subset\Bbb A^1_{\Bbb C}$ or the underlying points of $\Bbb A^1_\Bbb C$ and declare $\Bbb C[V]$ to be either $\Bbb C^n$ or $\Bbb C[x]$, respectively. For the other direction of the equivalence, there are two cases. If $|V|>|\Bbb C|$, then $|V| > |\Bbb A^n_\Bbb C|$ for any finite $n$, so there cannot be an injective map from $V$ to any $\Bbb A^n_\Bbb C$. If $|V|<|\Bbb C|$ but is not finite, this produces a contradiction because every $0$-dimensional affine variety is finite and every positive-dimensional affine variety has cardinality at least $|\Bbb C|$.

If your question was instead to show that the upper half-plane in the complex plane was not a Zariski-closed set, then this is much easier: the closed subsets of $\Bbb A^1_\Bbb C$ are either finite or the entire space, which you can easily derive from the fact that $\Bbb C[x]$, the coordinate algebra of $\Bbb A^1_\Bbb C$ is a PID with irreducible elements $0$ and $x-a$ for any $a\in\Bbb C$.